# Twitter Bootstrap collapsing navbar non responsive when clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, mean

I am new to using bootstrap and have creating the following navigation bar. It collapses just fine but none of my links show up when i click the button. I do have collapse.js located in a bower components folder within my project. So far, I have tried changing the data-target to #navbar-collapse and just plain navbar-collapse. Here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" data-ng-include="'/system/views/header.html'" data-role="navigation">
    <div data-ng-controller="HeaderController">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div style="float:left; width: 40%;">
            <ul style="text-align:right" class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">faq</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; width: 20%;">
            <a ui-sref="home" mean-token="'site-title'"><img src="/system/assets/img/blacklogo.jpg" width="140" height="60"/></a>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; width: 40%;">
            <div style="float:left;">
                <ul style="text-align:left" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
                    <li data-ng-hide="global.authenticated"><a href="#">tools</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <ul style="text-align:right" class="navbar-nav nav" data-ng-hide="global.authenticated">
                    <li><a ui-sref='auth.login'>login</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul style="text-align:right" class="navbar-nav nav" data-ng-show="global.authenticated">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            {{global.user.name}} <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/logout">Sign out</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

UPDATE - here is my head file, which is mostly a product of cloning the mean project from github and then using npm install commands to install bower and other stuff (sorry if that doesn't make sense.... I've only been using the MEAN stack for about a month now):

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

  <title>{{appName}} - {{title}}</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="keywords" content="node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb, angularjs, swig">
  <meta name="description" content="MEAN - A Modern Stack: MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, NodeJS. (BONUS: Passport User Support).">

  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID">
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{appName}} - {{title}}">
  <meta property="og:description" content="MEAN - A Modern Stack: MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS, NodeJS. (BONUS: Passport User Support).">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:url" content="APP_URL">
  <meta property="og:image" content="APP_LOGO">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="MEAN - A Modern Stack">
  <meta property="fb:admins" content="APP_ADMIN">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/aggregated.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/users/assets/css/login.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/system/assets/css/default.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/system/assets/css/navbar.css">

  <!-- Inline javascript. Can set the src /modules/aggregated.js?group=header-->
  <script type="text/javascript">{{headerJs|raw}}</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/js/collapse.js"></script>

  {% for file in assets.core.css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/{{file}}">
  {% endfor %}

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
```

Comment: If you're using Angular, then use https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap instead of Bootstrap's own JS.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your code on my local machine and the links show up for me.

You've probably forgot to include `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js`.

Moreover, your code shouldn't contain inline style. For instance, it's a bad practice to write:

```
    <div style="float:left; width: 40%;">
```

You should use css class for that.

Comment: yes, I will be moving all the styling to a css sheet, after I have it working correctly. Can you show me how you included those? I'm pretty sure they are built into my mean.io project and came in when I installed bower components. I also tried forcing collapse.js by putting the script in my head section.

Comment: Show us your head section please

Comment: I have updated the question to include my head code. I don't know why my previous comment has not been posted here

Comment: Well, I don't see any inclusion of bootstrap.min.js file.

Comment: hmm, wouldn't a lot of my other bootstrap stuff not work, if that was the case. I think it may be listed with whatever is in this line of code in the head file: <script type="text/javascript">{{headerJs|raw}}</script>, but the only header.js file I could find had nothing to do with scripts.

Comment: I added both js files directly to my head and the collapsed list still doesn't show a list when clicked. I updated the code to show the lines I added.

Comment: Can you try to add this js file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js we can see if it's a bower issue.

Comment: ok so i copied everything in your link to a file and then added that file to my head. Still it collapses just fine but nothing happens on the click.

Comment: What do you mean by "it collapses just fine"?

Comment: My whole question is based on the fact that the navigation bar menu items collapse from a horizontal bar to a little button in the upper right of the navbar. That has always worked just fine. The problem is that clicking the little button in the upper right doesn't do anything except change how the button looks (changes background color to match the mouse hover color).

Comment: Do others javascript bootstrap components work fine? For instance can you launch a modal? If yes, maybe we can look on a z-index issue if you made some customization.

Comment: I have an accordion working. If it's not a quick and easy fix (which it doesn't sound like it is) I'll just remove the whole collapse part of it. It's not too important to get that aspect of it to work. I appreciate your diligence, though. Thank you for trying.

Comment: you know what... I just tried to make a dropdown on a form and clicking does nothing. So it's not just an issue related to my navigation bar collapsing... it's the fact that dropdown doesn't seem to be working fully. thoughts?

Comment: Also should mention, my navbar has a dropdown for when logged in... that one does work as advertised.

Comment: "that one does work as advertised" Is it the same dropdown by bootstrap? So you say that a dropdown works on a page and another one doesn't on another page

Comment: By the way, if you have something online I can have a better check.

Comment: someone else working on the project reports having similar issues with modals... clicking the button initiate the modal has no effect. I'm gonna PM you our repo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65006/discussion-between-clanier9-and-benjamin-benoudis).